# Phantom Facebook Pages for different category pages on Website

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I would like to get the below structure on my website.  So when someone "likes" my main page or the kids category page they are dropped into my secret website on Facebook so I can occasionally post to their News Feed.

Website:  http://www.thebleeppeoplesay.com
Facebook Page Created: The Bleep People Say (using open graph meta tags)

and

http://wwwthebleeppeoplesay.com/category/kids
Facebook Page Created: The Bleep Kids Say (using open graph meta tags)

Is it possible to have two sets of meta tags within the same main domain?  I am using a simple Wordpress template with one header.php file for all pages within the website.  I am thinking there might be a way to put special code in the header that will call to code within category.php and index.php?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

refer to [Dynamic Facebook og Meta Tags in Wordpress PHP](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11075694/dynamic-facebook-og-meta-tags-in-wordpress-php) for adding meta tags to wordpress.  IF i find any better examples i will edit them in.